# How To remove a specific tag from XElement

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xelement

Please consider this `XML`:

```
<Employees>
    <Person>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>Nima</Name>
        <LName>Agha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1002</ID>
        <Name>Ligha</Name>
        <LName>Ligha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1003</ID>
        <Name>Jigha</Name>
        <LName>Jigha</LName>
    </Person>
</Employees>
```

I load it in to a `Xelement` variable.Now How I can remove second `Person` tag from above `XML`?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only condition is the second node Person, you can use this.

```
XElement  rootElement = .... // init your rootElement as you want 

rootElement.Elements("Person").Skip(1).Remove() ;
```